# Codeigniter URL Routing Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, router

I'm new to codeigniter and want to set my URLs on website currently I'm using version 3.0.1 URL looks like

```
http://oti.nhmp.net/index.php/site/about_us
```

I want it like this

```
http://oti.nhmp.net/about_us
```

i have tried URL routing in routes file but it's not working for me here is the code

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['about_us'] = "index.php/site/about_us";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]    

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: are you getting 404 error??

Comment: nope page is opening perfect, but just want to change the URL

Comment: here is the [Website URL](http://oti.nhmp.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your href for About us like this

```
<a href="http://oti.nhmp.net/about_us">About Us</a>
```

Comment: Have you specified the route in routes.php??

Comment: I'm using this right now `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/site/about_us">About Us</a>`

Comment: change it to <a href="<?php echo base_url("about_us"); ?>">About Us</a> and specify the route for about_us in routes.php file

Comment: I update the router and link both, but getting 404 Error

Comment: i updated the question with router code, please check

Comment: create .htaccess file in root and add the following code
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: @KashifLatif ass only what i have given in htaccess and check once.

Comment: .htaccess file, routes file and a href link all is according to you but still getting 404 page :)

Comment: remove index.php in your routes.php file, $route['about_us'] = "/site/about_us";

Comment: Without leading slash. So: `$route['about_us'] = "site/about_us";` and same way for others. Check the [manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) first, than code and ask. ;)